# DuckDB SQL Query ParserException: Error on executing SQL query with column name which includes # symbol

Tags: sql, azure-blob-storage, duckdb

When I tried to execute a query on DuckDB which accesses parquet file from Azure Blob Storage. It is showing parse ParserException at column names PatientDxICD-10Code#01,PatientDxICD-10Code#02.
Query and ParserException are given below.

```
                                              ^
```

Query:

```
select InvoiceNumber, InvoiceStatus, InvoiceSalesOrderNumber,\[PatientDxICD-10Code#01\],    \[PatientDxICD-10Code#02\]
from
read_parquet(\['https://blob_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/blob_container_name/History/Facts/Delta_Fact_Closed_Invoices/Fact_Closed_Invoices_04092023.parquet'\], hive_partitioning=false)
```

Exception:

```
Parser Error: syntax error at or near "Code"
LINE 2: ...InvoiceSalesOrderNumber,\[PatientDxICD-10Code#01\],  \[PatientDxICD-10Code#02\]
^
Traceback (most recent call last):

...........line 249, in generate_Fact_Closed_Invoices_Bellevue
df_delta = con.execute(query).df()

ParserException: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "Code"
LINE 2: ...InvoiceSalesOrderNumber,\[PatientDxICD-10Code#01\],  \[PatientDxICD-10Code#02\]
```

Please help me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 4):

DuckDB does not use `[...]` to escape column names, use `"` instead.
E.g. `select InvoiceNumber, InvoiceStatus, InvoiceSalesOrderNumber, "PatientDxICD-10Code#01" ...`.
The brackets are used to create lists.

Comment: @Community, this is not a useful comment.

Answer (score 0):

duckdb do not permit to use '-' in columns name.
So, column name's '-' change to '_' , then duckdb SQL work.
Or, use pandas etc to read data, make alias to change name.